# How to use handle in WINAPI when I implement my c++ code with RAII principle?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, handle, raii

What is the best way for using HANDLE object from WINAPI when I want to write my code consider RAII principle in c++

I write the following code:

```
bool Uninstall(wstring folder, const bool removeDir = NULL)
{
    //init for run over file in dir by winapi
    unique_ptr<WIN32_FIND_DATA> ffd = make_unique<WIN32_FIND_DATA>();
    HANDLE handle;
    wstring path_for_search = folder + L"\\*"; // for include all the things in path when run over    the files or directories
    //List files
    handle = FindFirstFileW(path_for_search.c_str(), ffd.get());
    // run over files and directories by handle
    do {
        if (wcscmp(ffd->cFileName, L".") != 0 && wcscmp(ffd->cFileName, L"..") != 0) // pass the default '.' and ".." 
        {
            wstring file_or_dir_path = folder + L"\\" + ffd->cFileName; // get the full file or dir path
            if (GetFileAttributes(file_or_dir_path.c_str()) & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) // check if directory
            {
                Uninstall(file_or_dir_path, false); // recursive call for uninstall the content in the sub dir itself your text
            }
            else
            {
                DeleteFileW(file_or_dir_path.c_str()); // delete the file
            }
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(handle, ffd.get()));
    FindClose(handle);
    delete handle;
    //check if remove the original dir
    if (!removeDir)
    {
        RemoveDirectoryW(folder.c_str());
    }
    return true;
}
```

But I'm not sure How to implement automatic RAII class for this object.

Comment: For a generic `HANDLE` that must be passed to `CloseHandle`, you can still use a standard smart pointer but with a custom deleter that calls `CloseHandle`. Easily translatable to `FindFirstFile` and `FindClose`.

Comment: Create a [smart pointer class](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15351/Implementing-a-simple-smart-pointer-in-c) whose destructor calls CloseHandle().

Comment: Also note that since the C++17 standard [C++ have a filesystem namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) which can do what your shown code is doing but in a standard and simple C++ way (like using iterators etc.).

Comment: By the way, `delete handle;`? Only `delete` what is explicitly received by `new`. Don't `delete` anything you didn't `new`.

Comment: Also `const bool removeDir = NULL`? First of all `NULL` is a C backward compatible macro for null pointers. If you want to set a `bool` variable use the standard `true` and `false` values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks!! can you write an example of smart pointer in this case?

Comment: Duplicate of [Implementing RAII on a folder iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62615721/implementing-raii-on-a-folder-iteration)

Comment: Can you repair my code with your comments? @HansPassant

Comment: @OhadPorat Searching the internet for `FindFirstFileW RAII` could have saved you some time.

Comment: unique_ptr<> does not have a destructor that calls CloseHandle().  You have to make your own class.  If the link doesn't help you then maybe leave this on the shelf for a while.

Comment: The [WIL](https://github.com/microsoft/wil) provides [`unique_hfind`](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/wiki/RAII-resource-wrappers#available-unique_any-handle-types) for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is to make a deleter that can call `FindClose`:

```
struct FindCloser {
  typedef HANDLE pointer;
  void operator()(HANDLE h) const {FindClose(h);}
};
```

And then we make a typedef:

```
using FindHandle = std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, FindCloser>;
```

And then RAII in your code is trivial:

```
FindHandle handle = FindFirstFileW(path_for_search.c_str(), ffd.get());
```

You'll probably also want similar for CloseHandle:

```
struct HandleCloser {
    typedef HANDLE pointer;
    void operator()(HANDLE h) const {CloseHandle(h);}
};
using RaiiHandle = std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, HandleCloser>;
```

In theory, one could use a `std::unique_ptr<void,BOOL(WINAPI *)(HANDLE)>` and then pass `CloseHandle` as a second parameter to the constructor, but that's (A) obnoxious, (B) bigger and (C) slower. The `FindCloser` struct is stateless (takes 0 bytes in memory), and is trivially inlinable.  A `BOOL(WINAPI *)(HANDLE)` takes an extra ~8 bytes in each `unique_ptr`, and is harder for the compiler to prove that the `BOOL(WINAPI *)(HANDLE)` will always point at `FindClose`, so it often can't be inlined.

Comment: Can't the custom deleter be a lambda?  I would think that would be neater.

Comment: @PaulSanders: It could, but you'd have to have `std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, decltype(FindCloserLambda)>`, which is a little odd, but works. The lambda has to be declared and defined before the pointer is made though, so there's not much point.

Comment: Why would `std::unique_ptr<void,BOOL(WINAPI *)(HANDLE)>` be slower than (presumably) a custom deleter, that does the same thing?

Comment: @IInspectable I clarified. The `FindCloser` struct is stateless (takes 0 bytes in memory), and is trivially inlinable.  A `BOOL(WINAPI *)(HANDLE)` takes an extra ~8 bytes in each `unique_ptr`, and is harder for the compiler to prove that the `BOOL(WINAPI *)(HANDLE)` will always point at `FindClose`, so it often can't be inlined.